# Mocking Math.random() using Spock framework

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I am trying to mock the random method of the class math. I already tried using

```
def m = GrovyMock(Math)
m.random() >> 0.995
```

but it doesn't work and nothing is mocked. Does anyone knows a good solution?

Comment: What does not work? I guess, as [Java's doc of Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) states, it is a static method. AFAIK static methods cannot be mocked at all - and are bad coding style anyway. Better use an instance of Math.Random() - or even decouple the software from Math.random() or Random() by using an own interface.

Comment: @BitLauncher thank you I used Random() and now is working!

Comment: FYI, you can mock static methods if you use additional tools like Mockito, PowerMock, Sarek. The latter even supports mocking JRE bootstrap classes. But if you can avoid mocking static methods, I agree it is always better. BTW, a `GroovyMock` can mock static methods, but only when such a method is called by a Groovy class. If the code under test is Java or another non-Groovy language, the mock behaves just like a normal Spock mock, as is documented in the Spock manual. So inflationary use of Groovy mocks does not help you there.